# Why is the Munin server giving just 404 status when hitting /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph?

Tags: munin

I am using an Amazon Linux distribution (a recent one). I'm trying to install munin in the local node (just one node, both node and master). So I tried:

```
$ sudo yum install munin munin-node httpd mod_fcgid
```

Then I edited /etc/munin/munin.conf:

```
# cgi on demand
html_strategy cgi
graph_strategy cgi
```

Then I activated the service:

```
$ sudo chkconfig munin-node on
```

I checked the version:

```
$ munin-node-configure --version
Version:
    This is munin-node-configure (munin-node) v2.0.20.
[... more text here ...]
```

I ensured the munin.conf had the ScriptAlias directive:

```
<directory /var/www/html/munin>

AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd
AuthName "Munin"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault M310
</directory>
ScriptAlias /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph /var/www/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph
```

I ensured the password is set to a good password:

```
$ sudo htpasswd -c /etc/munin/munin-htpasswd MyUser
#stdin < my password
```

Then I restarted the service:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/munin restart
```

And my httpd:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

But hitting /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph raises a 404. But this 404 is not an Apache-like 404, but a totally empty 404 error, with no content at all, as if it was given by the cgi script. The httpd error_log shows nothing.

What should I check? What's my problem?

Answer (score 3):

Check if your apache/httpd is loading the `fcgid` or `cgi` module.

```
apachectl -M | grep cgi
```

Should respond

```
cgi_module (shared)
```

or

```
fcgid_module (shared)
```

(or both).

If its not there **enable it** with

```
sudo a2enmod cgi
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, by saying: "*...But hitting /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph raises a 404...*" you are not reporting the complete URL that raised mentioned 404. Please note that you need to call the munin-cgi-graph CGI with proper parameters and that those parameters will be properly validated by munin itself.

In other words, here on my side, this URL:

```
https://my.monitoring.server/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph/SAN/SAN/SAN_SW_Brocade1-pinpoint=1435589472,1435697472.png?&lower_limit=&upper_limit=&size_x=800&size_y=400
```

will produce following graph:

[image]

while this other URL:

```
https://my.monitoring.server/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph/something_random/here_and_there
```

will last in the 404 error you probably mentioned:

```
verzulli@iMac-Chiara:~$ wget https://my.monitoring.server/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph/something_random/here_and_there
--2015-06-30 23:02:39--  https://my.monitoring.server/cgi-bin/munin-cgi-graph/something_random/here_and_there
[....]
Richiesta HTTP inviata, in attesa di risposta... 404 Not Found
2015-06-30 23:02:40 ERRORE 404: Not Found.

verzulli@iMac-Chiara:~$
```

This is an intended behaviour of the munin-cgi-graph CGI. A quick look of the source code will show this:

```
while (new CGI::Fast) {
    # 1rst thing is to validate the URL. Only a subset of chars are allowed.
    # Return 404 if not compliant, w/o logging.
    [...]
}
```

Should the rendering process handled by munin-cgi-graph fail, chances are high that something will be logged in `/var/log/munin/munin-cgi-graph.log` (...your LOG path could be different, according to your own configuration).

As dynamic-graph-generation can be slightly tricky, you could carefully review the documentation [here](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI) and [here](http://munin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example/index.html).

If problem persists, please, provide further details.

## Update 1

As for the proper way to access munin web-interface, please consider that on the munin-server all the monitoring activities are launched by a cron-job (`munin-cron`) that starts launching a `munin-update` jobs and ends with a `munin-html` and `munin-graph` jobs.

The web-pages are managed by `munin-html` that will generate/update web pages according to the `html-dir` directives in the `munin.conf` file.

A default install could looks like:

- `munin.conf`: `htmldir /var/www/html/munin`

that together with a default Apache install, will let your munin web-interface accessible at `http://your.monitoring.server/munin`

---

*P.S.: A final personal note: even tough it might be easier to ask for support here on ServerFault, I suggest you to approach your munin/monitoring issues more organically, searching/reading ad-hoc documentation/tutorials. Even if at first it might be more challenging, I guarrantee you that in the long run you will be paid back :-)*

Comment: I'm a n00b at Munin. Never used it before and the documentation is quote poor regardin web access. What is the first entry point? Assuming I have a webserver and munin in strategy="cgi"... what's the first url I should manually hit in the browser?

Comment: Difficult to say without checking the CFG. Nevertheless, I guess that a simple "/munin" should be enough. Have you tried starting from there?

Comment: I've updated my answer so to include some details about web-interface (with also a personal advice) :-)

Comment: I will try. Last time I saw, visiting such url (i.e. /munin in my webserver, according to path /var/www/munin) showed me an index directory (with /static inside).